# Form data not writing to CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have an HTML form to capture some product data. When submitted, this should echo the data to the user in a table, as well as add to a CSV file. The echo part works, but won't write to the CSV.

Code is included below. I've only included the "ItemName" for brevity, but that seems to work.

```
$file_open = fopen("data.csv","a");
$no_rows = count(file("data.csv"));
$itemID = $no_rows+1;
$fclose($file_open);


$itemDataArray = array(
    'ID' => $no_rows,
    'ItemName' => $_POST['itemName'],
    'ItemImage' => $_POST['itemImage'],
    'ItemCapacity' => $_POST['itemCapacity'],
    'ItemFuelType' => $_POST['itemFuelType'],
    'ItemDescription' => $_POST['itemDescription'],
    'ItemFits' => $_POST['itemFits'],
    'ItemPrice' => $_POST['itemPrice'],
);

$file_open = fopen("data.csv","w");
fputcsv($file_open, $itemDataArray);

fclose($file); 

?>  
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Your record was added</title>


</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Detail</th>
      <th scope="col">Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Name</td>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['itemName']; ?></td>
    </tr>

....

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Even deleting data.csv has no effect, so I'm guessing it just isn't working at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a new line, [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with 'a' as second argument.

```
$file_open = fopen('data.csv', 'a');
```

[image]
Also, you have a typo in your code:

```
$fclose($file_open); // '$' here is wrong
```

And the last fclose($file) should be ($file_open);

Answer (score 0):

wrong

$fclose($file_open);   //wrong
correct

fclose($file_open);   //correct`